# is it possible to find random floats in range [a,b] in python?

Tags: python, random, floating-point

I'm trying to generate in python random floats in the range of [0.8,0.9] , but unfortanetly all the tools i found could only generate randoms in the range of [a,b) for floats. ( like `Random.uniform(a,b)` )

Meanwhile , I tried doing something like this :

```
uniform(0.8,0.90000000001)
```

but thats realy bad

any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between [0.8, 0.9] and [0.8,0.9) is vanishingly small.  Given the limitations of binary floating-point, I don't think there even is a difference, since 0.9 can't be precisely represented anyway.  Use [0.8,0.9).

Comment: There is a difference, because the limitations of floating-point also apply to the upper bound to `uniform`.  That is, when you say `uniform(0.8,0.9)`, you're actually saying something closer to `uniform(0.80000000000000004,0.90000000000000002)`.  The difference between [a,b) and [a,b] here is the difference between the maximum value being (approximately) 0.89999999999999991 and 0.90000000000000002.  It's not likely to happen, but the difference is there.

Comment: Both answer and comment are excellent points. I've never considered applying a uniform distribution to floating point values before, just because in nature between any two numbers you've got an infinite amount of numbers which are each infinitesimally probable. I suppose given precision constraints on fp numbers you COULD do this. Using a uniform distribution between say 8,000,000,000,000,000 and 9,000,000,000,000,001 would give you the distribution you are looking for without the pitfalls of f-p arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the `random.uniform()` docstring:

> Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding.

So you don't even know if the endpoint is included or not.  But you should not care either -- there are 900719925474100 floating point numbers in the range [0.8, 0.9].  It will take a lifetime until a single one of them occurs anyway, so there is no practical difference to including the endpoint or not, even if the endpoint can be represented exactly as a floating point number.

Comment: There are far fewer *uniform* random numbers in any given range than there are *possible* random numbers, because floating-point numbers are by definition nonuniform.

Comment: @Glenn:  The range [0.8, 0.9] happens to be uniform, since the exponent of both numbers in IEEE binary representation is the same.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of generating exactly an endpoint value should be negligible. What bad consequences do you worry about if you just use `Random.uniform(0.8,0.9)`? (And are you also worried about the fact that the double-precision floats you get when you say "`0.8`" and "`0.9`" aren't in fact exactly 8/10 and 9/10?)

It's possible that you have very unusual requirements; but for, say, 99.9% of applications I think the answer is: just use `Random.uniform(a,b)` and don't worry about it.

Comment: McCaugehan -Actually I dont . I'm trying to simulate something and this is the range of the possible probabilty for that to happen. I was wandering why I couldn't find any tool that will give that

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) say that `uniform(a, b)` generates a number in [a, b]<sup>1</sup>, but this appears to be a documentation error, since the [source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup) shows it to rely on `random()`, which, according to the docs, returns [0.0, 1.0)<sup>2</sup>.

If you must have [a, b], then you can try generating this range from an integer:

```
random.inclusive_uniform = lambda a, b:
    random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF) / float(0xFFFFFFFF) * (b - a) + a
```

I say "try" generating this range, because when the bounds cannot be precisely represented (neither 0.8 and 0.9 can be precisely represented in IEEE-754), then the range is actually [a', b'], where a' and b' are whatever a and b get rounded to.  Note that this might even be greater than the range [a, b], so beware!

<sub><sup>1</sup> Specifically, it says that return value `N` is limited to `a <= N <= b`.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> In a comment in the source, however, is an assertion that it can never actually be 0.0, so I guess range is actually (0.0, 1.0).</sub>

Comment: The docs say that it may be [a,b] or [a,b).  It's much clearer in the docstring than in the needlessly wordy HTML documentation--which, for some reason, doesn't use range notation--but it's in there ("The end-point value b may or may not be included...").

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: The source shows neither [a, b] nor [a, b) to be true.  If you read enough through the source, you'll see that x, y, and z will never be zero, which means that N will never come closer than approximately `0.0099% * (b - a)` of either b or a.  To the OP, this could be significant, since it means that `random.uniform(0.8, 0.9)` will be in the range [0.8000099011045553, 0.8999900988954448].

Comment: Maybe, though being in a marginally smaller range is typically safer than ending up out of range.  For example, if you're doing something like `1/(1-n)` expecting n = [0,1), then having n = 1 will cause division by zero.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard:  Granted.  The OP's case doesn't appear susceptible to that particular problem, but no doubt that out of range may be a problem, and I warned about that.  On the other hand, I may have blown it out of proportion.  It may be out of range of [0.8, 0.9] (depending on the platform's parsing method), but it won't be out of range of [a, b].  That is, the loss of precision, and rounding to a binary fraction, occurs when 0.8 and 0.9 are parsed to `a` and `b`.  No further errors should occur in `random.inclusive_uniform()`.

Comment: Anyone who really needs clear, predictable, uniform results should use fixed-point math anyway.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard:  No doubt.  `random.inclusive_uniform()` can just as easily use `decimal.Decimal()` instead of `float()`.

Answer (score 1):

If it really matters, then you can do this:

```
def uniform_closed(a, b):
     while True:
         r = random.uniform(a, b + (b - a) * 0.01)
         if r <= b: return r
```