# Generate a random number from an interval in Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

How to generate a random number in the interval [-0.5, 0.5] using Python `random()` or `randrange()` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will do the trick `random.random() - .5`

Comment: Thank you! is the upper bound inclusive?

Comment: No. The upper bound is exclusive, but the lower bound is inclusive.

Comment: random.random() always has an exclusive upper bound, but sometimes random.uniform() will have an inclusive upper bound. Here is a stack overflow question that discusses this further -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249717/is-it-possible-to-find-random-floats-in-range-a-b-in-python

Answer (score 9):

random returns a float and takes no arguments, randrange takes an upper and lower bound but takes and returns an int.

```
from random import randrange

print(randrange(-5, 5))
```

If you want floats use [uniform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform):

```
from random import  uniform

uniform(-.5, .5)
```

Comment: Thank you, `uniform` does return a float from the interval [-.5, .5], however, I wanted to know how to do it without using `uniform` but only `random()` or randrange()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `random()` and use a varying bound, you could easily do:

```
from random import random
upper_limit = 0.5
lower_limit = -0.5
random() * (upper_limit - lower_limit) + lower_limit
```

This will always give you a random float between -0.5 and 0.5.